# How to apply Header Image in itextsharp Html to pdf convertor

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

Please give me any solution; I am using this code:

```
 HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("This is a header"), false);
 document.Header = header;
```

but this error occured:

> CS0246:
>  
>    The type or namespace name 'HeaderFooter' could not be found (are you
>    missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 1):

That code was [deprecated and removed many years ago](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/HeaderFooter-class-td3027962.html) but still lives on in comments in the source code unfortunately.

What you want to do is subclass the `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper` class and handle the `OnEndPage` method which will get called once for every page in your document:

```
public class MyPageEventHandler : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper {
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        //Create a simple ColumnText object
        var CT = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
        //Bind it to the top of the document but take up the entire page width
        CT.SetSimpleColumn(0, document.PageSize.Height - 20, document.PageSize.Width, document.PageSize.Height);
        //Add some text
        CT.AddText(new Phrase("This is a test"));
        //Draw our ColumnText object
        CT.Go();
    }
}
```

To use this you just bind a new instance of it to your `PdfWriter`'s `PageEvent` property:

```
writer.PageEvent = new MyPageEventHandler();
```

Below is a full working C# 2010 WinForms app targeting iTextSharp 5.1.2.0 that shows this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //Test file to create
            string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.pdf");
            //Standard PDF file stream creation
            using (FileStream output = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None)){
                using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER)) {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output)) {

                        //Bind our custom event handler to the PdfWriter
                        writer.PageEvent = new MyPageEventHandler();
                        //Open our PDF for writing
                        document.Open();

                        //Add some text to page 1
                        document.Add(new Paragraph("This is page 1"));
                        //Add a new page
                        document.NewPage();
                        //Add some text to page 2
                        document.Add(new Paragraph("This is page 2"));

                        //Close the PDF
                        document.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            this.Close();
        }
    }
    public class MyPageEventHandler : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper {
        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
            //Create a simple ColumnText object
            var CT = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
            //Bind it to the top of the document but take up the entire page width
            CT.SetSimpleColumn(0, document.PageSize.Height - 20, document.PageSize.Width, document.PageSize.Height);
            //Add some text
            CT.AddText(new Phrase("This is a test"));
            //Draw our ColumnText object
            CT.Go();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we use the PageEventHandler to add HTML to the top of the file. The CSS is too restrictive to allow relative positioning?

Comment: @DanielCasserly, your comment would be better answered if it were posted as a dedicated question including what you've tried, what works, what doesn't work, what you expect, etc. Also, please remember that iText does not deal with HTML in any way. There is a helper library from iText that converts HTML strings into PDF objects if/when possible but these are still PDF objects.

Comment: thanks for that, In actual fact I found what I was looking for with the OnStartPage override method in the same class (using the XMLWorkerHelper parsing). Thanks anyway.