# Is it possible to add a header to a generated PDF?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf-generation, itext

I have an image I would like to use as a header for a PDF that I am generating using the code below. Is it possible to do this? Thanks!

```
   Dim Doc1 As New Document
    Dim path As String = "" + Session("Username") + "\"
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) Then

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
    End If
    Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", random)
    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))
    Dim ev As New itsEvents
    pdfWrite.PageEvent = ev

    Doc1.Open()
    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))

    Doc1.Close()
End Sub
Public Class itsEvents
    Inherits PdfPageEventHelper
    Public Overrides Sub OnStartPage(ByVal writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, ByVal document As iTextSharp.text.Document)
        Dim ch As New Chunk("This is my header " & writer.PageNumber)
        document.Add(ch)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/9996793/231316

Comment: I tried this but doesnt like this      Doc1.AddHeader(New Header("test", "~/Header.png")

Comment: @user1342164 - please define "doesn't like this".  We're not mind readers, if you won't post the actual exception messages, we cannot help.

Comment: Ok sorry, I found out how to get a header see edited code above. But how can I refernce an image instead of using the text "This is my header"?